# IRC bot, making a list of banned words?

Tags: python

So currently my problem with this bot for my Twitch channel is that it prevents me from having multiple words in 1 string while Authlist is being threated as an list.

Example:
I want to ban the words foo1, foo2, foo3 and foo4 but while having them all in 1 string I need to type all 4 of them in chat in order that my bot is able to ban the person, but not if he says one of the 4 words.

Thanks in advance!

```
import socket

authlist = "patyyebot patyye"
banword = "foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4"
server = "patyye.jtvirc.com"
name = "patyyebot"
port = 6667
channel = "#patyye"
password = "xx"
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((server, port))
irc.send("PASS " + password + "\n")
irc.send("NICK " + name + "\n")
irc.send("USER patyyebot patyyebot patyyebot :PatyYeBot\n")
irc.send("JOIN " + channel + "\n")
while True:

    def message(msg):
        irc.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :" + msg + "\n")
    def ban(msg):
        irc.send("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :/ban " + msg + "\n")


    data = irc.recv(1204)
    data = data.strip('\r\n')
    senderusr = data.split(" ")
    senderusr = senderusr[0]
    senderusr = senderusr.split("!")
    senderusr = senderusr[0]
    senderusr = senderusr.strip(":")

    print data
    if data.find == "PONG" :
        irc.send("PING")

    if "!facebook" in data and senderusr in authlist:
        message("@" + senderusr + ": Facebook is private")

    if "!twitter" in data:
        message("Follow PatyYe on Twitter: https://twitter.com/PatyYe")

    if data in banword:
        message("@" + senderusr + ":  zei een gebanned woord! Ban uitgevoerd")
        ban(senderusr)
```

Comment: It's a little hard for me to understand exactly what you mean.
Do you only want to ban if all 4 words appear or 1 of them is enough?
Can you rephrase your criteria?

Comment: I think he want's to ban any single one of the words. You should split the string into an array (space being the delimiter). Then loop over the array and look for the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `yourstring.split()` to split the space-delimited string of banned words into a list:

```
>>> banned_string = "word1 word2 word3"
>>> banned_string.split()
['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
```

Then you can iterate over the words and look for them in the message.

Full example:

```
def checkmessage(msg):
    banned_words = "badword1 badword2 badword3"
    banned_list= banned_words.split()

    for word in banned_list:
         if word in msg:
             print("banned for saying: " + word)
             return
    print("not banned")


msg1 = "Nothing special here"
msg2 = "I say the badword2."

checkmessage(msg1)
checkmessage(msg2)
```

Executing that program results in:

```
not banned
banned for saying: badword2
```

Comment: I did add some functionality to have the words in a file so it will check now if its a banned word or not!
def checkmessage(msg):
 banfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
     banned_words = banfile.read()
     banned_list= banned_words.split()
 banfile.close()

Comment: @PatrickKnobbout Good you got it to work. You should mark this answer as accepted, so the question gets "solved". Feel free to upvote too :)

Comment: (or the other answer if you like)

Comment: @varesa: earning rep is not so easy anymore. You deserve some, I'm upvoting. :-)

Comment: @PauloScardine Back then I didn't even realize there was another answer. I just wanted to tell him to accept an answer in the case he was new to so. I added the second comment when I realized there was a second answer :)

Comment: @varesa: I know, was just trying to motivate you (English is not my native idiom, forgive me if I sounded condescending), my upvote is sincere.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions you can avoid the loop and check all words in one pass.

You can censor just the banned words (if you are logging/archiving the conversations):

```
>>> banned_words = "phuck azz deeck peach"
>>> regexp = '|'.join(banned_words.split())
>>> message = "You son of a peach!"
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(regexp, '[beeeeeep]', message)
'You son of a [beeeeeep]!'
```

Or you can test for the banned words and ban the user:

```
>>> if re.search(regexp, message): print "Consider yourself banned, sir!"
... 
Consider yourself banned, sir!
```

[update]

Jon wrote:

> Probably best to put banned_words into descending length order (to match longest words first) and running them through re.escape just in case... – Jon Clements

Depending on the list source you may want to escape sequences that have special meaning for regular expressions, just to be safe.

```
>>> ordered_list = sorted(banned_words.split(), key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
>>> ordered_list
['phuck', 'deeck', 'peach', 'azz']
>>> regexp = '|'.join([re.escape(word) for word in ordered_list])
>>> regexp
'phuck|deeck|peach|azz'
```

You probably want to enhance the regular expression in order to make it case insensitive and to match word boundaries (preventing false positives).

> It might also be a good idea to wrap the regexp in \b(...)\b, lest you accidentally ban someone for saying "impeachment" (or, more realistically, "Scunthorpe"). – Ilmari Karonen

Remember you have to escape the backslashes (or use raw strings):

```
>>> regexp = r'\b(' + regexp + r')\b'
>>> regexp
'\\b(phuck|deeck|peach|azz)\\b'
```

Comment: Probably best to put banned_words into descending length order (to match longest words first) and running them through `re.escape` just in case...

Comment: It might also be a good idea to wrap the regexp in `\b(...)\b`, lest you accidentally ban someone for saying "impeachment" (or, more realistically, "[Scunthorpe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)").